# What's keeping my heroku dyno awake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku is telling me my app is staying awake, but my church website has very very low traffic (like maybe three hits a day). So what's keeping it busy? I have Zerigo DNS :: Zerigodns addon; could that be it, since it's a dns manager? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start investigating are the [Heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)

```
$ heroku logs
```

The logs will show you the latest requests that hit your app. However, the log may not reveal the kind of client that accessed your website.

In order to determine the client, you can temporary add a callback in your app that prints in the log the request user agent.

Keep in mind that a public website may be accessed by a number of clients including search engine crawlers. These clients will effectively generate a request from Heroku point of view even if they don't show up as a visitor in your analytics software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding [papertrail addon](https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail) and see what's keeping your dyno awake. Or for that matter any addon which monitors log can help you.